# Android - Toast message every 1 minute

Tags: android, service, android-service, alarmmanager, toast

I am trying to implement a service in Android that displays a toast message every 1 minute in Android. I am new to Android development and learned about AlarmManager that will help me do this. I have implemented the code in the following way:

This is my IIManagerActivity class

```
package com.example.iimanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IIManagerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iimanager);
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(this, SampleService.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/900, pi);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_iimanager, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my SampleService that is meant to display a toast message.
For some reason I cannot get to see a toast message no matter how long I wait.

```
package com.example.iimanager;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SampleService extends IntentService {

    public SampleService() {
        super("SimpleService");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         //do something
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong and what needs to be done to get it corrected?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just curious...why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the below 3 lines for toast call

> Timer timer = new Timer();
>     TimerTask updateProfile = new SampleService(SampleService.this);
>     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 10,1000);

```
class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {
private Context context;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        // Write Custom Constructor to pass Context
    public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
        this.context = con;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    });
}
}).start();

}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static final long INTERVAL=60000;//variable for execute services every 1 minute
private Handler mHandler=new Handler(); // run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Timer mTimer=null; // timer handling

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported Operation");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if service is  already existed
        if(mTimer!=null)
            mTimer.cancel();
    else
            mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);// schedule task
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//display toast when method called
    mTimer.cancel();//cancel the timer
}
//inner class of TimeDisplayTimerTask
private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast at every 1 minute
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//load the layout file
    startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));//use to start the services
}
}
```

Also add this code in your manifest file

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: What should be done with this code? Code is not enough. Tell what you changed. Brake it down to the important parts. Thanks.

Comment: Using this code you can implement a service in Android that displays a toast message every 1 minute in Android.Thanks,hope it useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a Timer object.Then use the `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask)` to repeat the Toast message.

Answer (score -2):

You can just make a looping thread which contains your code.

Like this:

```
public class Toaster extends Thread{                      
    public void run(){              
    //Your code to loop

    thread.sleep(60000)           
         }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `sleep(...)` is a hack. There are better ways to do what the OP wants.